# Not able to update the database in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I am using hibernate 3.0 with MySQL and I want to make the simple database operations like insert update and delete with the database.I am getting the successful results for insert and delete but not able to update the particular field.
I have persistent class named Employee with Fname,Lname,Id and mail with getters and setters.

This is my main method :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;
    Random r = new Random();
    try {
        /*
         * This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml
         * 
         * and prepare hibernate for use
         */
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact = (Contact) session.get(Contact.class, new Long(1));
        // Create new instance of Contact and set
        // values in it by reading them from form object
        System.out.println("Inserting Record");
        contact.setId(r.nextLong() % 100);
        contact.setFirstName("123anand");
        contact.setLastName("nandurbarkar");
        contact.setEmail("anand_it1990@yahoo.com");
        trx.commit();
        session.update(contact);
```

And this is my conf file :-

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatetutorial</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- Mapping files -->
 <mapping resource="contact.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please help if u know how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do your update before you commit the session

So swapping your last two lines around should make it work:-

```
session.update(contact);  
trx.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the id of an entity. If you want to see how update of other properties works, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;
    Random r = new Random();
    try {
        /*
         * This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml
         * 
         * and prepare hibernate for use
         */
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();
        Contact contact = new Contact();

        // Create new instance of Contact and set
        // values in it by reading them from form object
        System.out.println("Inserting Record");
        contact.setId(r.nextLong() % 100);
        contact.setFirstName("123anand");
        contact.setLastName("nandurbarkar");
        contact.setEmail("anand_it1990@yahoo.com");
        // this makes contact persistent. No SQL commands yet
        session.persist(contact);
        // sync the session. Here you get a SQL INSERT
        session.flush();

        // change some properties
        contact.setFirstName("ugo");

        // sync again.Here you get a SQL UPDATE
        session.flush()

        // Now, let's say you want to update an existing instance/record
        // with id = 123
        // retrieve the instance
        Contact c = session.get(Contact.class, new Long(123));
        c.setFirstName("new name");

        // sync the session with the db
        session.flush(); // <- here you get SQL UPDATE

        trx.commit();
```

Comment: Ya agree to this point.but what if I want to update at a particular record ? Lets say if Id=1 that contact name should be changed to "abc".So how can I achieve this ? For that shouldn't I use this :-                                          contact = (Contact) session.get(Contact.class, new Long(1));

Comment: Yes, you should use session.get(). I added a couple of line to the code in order to exemplify this. Other option is to retrieve instances with HQL queries. This is vary basic usage of Hibernate, you'll find much more use case and samples in the excellent reference documentation.